# Why doesn't tor connect to Socks4/5 proxies?

Tags: firefox, socks, vidalia, https

I can only connect to HTTPS proxies using FF's proxy feature.
When i put in a socks4/5 proxy in FF, it doesn't connect to the proxy. Can anybody confirm this behaviour ?

My setup:

proxychains v4.14 conf: socks5 enabled,
vidalia standalone v0.2.21,
tor v0.4.4.5-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb + tor-geoipdb_0.4.4.5-1~bpo10+1_all.deb,
FF-ESR v78.3

Comment: Tor does not provide an HTTP GET proxy. Are you setting your SOCKS proxy settings in FF directly, or in proxychains?

Comment: @Steve I put the socks4/5 proxy in FF's settings which doesnt work. but when i add an socks4/5 proxy after tor in proxychains it works. is this the right behaviour ?

Comment: I don't understand your setup. What SOCKS proxies are you using, Tor's SOCKS proxy right? And if you put Tor's SOCKS proxy in to FF settings you don't get internet, but if you put Tor's SOCKS proxy into proxychains and start FF you do get internet?

Comment: @Steve im using socks4/5 from hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/. not working setup: proxychains>tor>FF with external socks4/5. working setup: proxychains>tor+external socks4/5>FF with direct connection.